# Object does not match target type using C# Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to get a value of a Window as follows

**this** refers to the main window (window1)

```
Type type = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("Left");
object obj = pi.GetValue(type, null);
```

But I get an "Object does not match target type using" error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Because you are trying to get the 'Left' property of a Type, not your instance.

try this

```
object obj = pi.GetValue(this, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

`object obj = property.GetValue(currentObject, null)`;

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Comment: this works when you have string or any non complex type inside a property as a value, you should send the currentObject (Object which is used to get property) as a parameter instead of this