# Property reflection - How to get value?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a need to get properties and their values dynamically. My code below is failing. Can someone give me a hand? I have tried numerous examples but nothing so far.

```
        Dim seriesName As String = s.SeriesName
        If model.Settings.ShowNativeLanguage Then

            Dim propInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = s.GetType().GetProperty(model.Country)
            seriesName = CStr(propInfo.GetValue(s, Nothing))

        End If
```

This code produces the error "Object does not match target type."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was already answered here for C# [Object does not match target type using C# Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244607/object-does-not-match-target-type-using-c-sharp-reflection)

The solution is to change this line of your code:

```
seriesName = propInfo.GetValue(propInfo, Nothing).ToString()
```

to this:

```
seriesName = propInfo.GetValue(s, Nothing).ToString()
```

You need to pass the object of which you want to get the value. (More information in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1))

**Update:**

You should always check reflection results for `Nothing` values. So first store the output of `propInfo.GetValue(s, Nothing)` in a temporary variable and later on only call the `ToString()`-function if the object is not `Nothing`

Comment: Yep, I had tried this according to that example. For whatever reason I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Check out my updates on the code. Maybe the "s" object project is causing it to fail?

Comment: Your property is probably returning `Nothing` see my answer update

Comment: seriesName = CStr(propInfo.GetValue(s, Nothing)) fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Surely that should be:

```
 ... propInfo.GetValue(s) ...
```

Normally you must pass the object representing the `this` instance as the first parameter. You are getting that error because it's expecting the instance `s`, not a `PropertyInfo` instance.